# Virtual machine hanging on shudown

Tags: kvm, qemu, shutdown

I asked this over on 'Ask Ubuntu'; it got upvoted but didn't attract an answer so I am moving it here.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.2 fully updated. I have a virtual machine running 14.04.5 using kvm and qemu. The machine runs fine except when I go to shut it down. It hangs in the same place on every shutdown, maxing out its cpu allocation. I have searched the logs, but have found nothing of interest. I run xfce4 and virtual manager, so I can get a pic of where in hangs in the shutdown process.

[image: screen grab of hung shutdown]

My question is: How can I best diagnose this problem? Is there someway I can find out precisely what is causing it to hang? Perhaps additional logging?